# how can we express finiteness as a first order property?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic, foundations

I don't know much about set theory but I read that in ZFC a set is finite when there are no bijections from the set to a proper subset of itself. It seems to me however that quantifying over subsets or over all functions is not first order (correct me if I'm wrong). So is it possible to express finitess as a first order property? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence $\psi(A)$ given by $$\forall x(x\subset A\land x\neq A\to \forall f(f\text { is a function from }A \text{ to }x\to f\text{ is not injective}))$$ is first order, and is true iff $A$ is finite.

Comment: This doesn't really address the concerns in the question. Since in general quantifying over functions is not first order. The point here is that ZFC treats functions as objects of the universe which makes this a first order quantification after all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila True. I haven't studied much set theory, but the only context that I have encountered in ZFC where it mattered that things were first order was when characterising the complexity of a set, i.e. how many unbounded quantifiers you need to define it.

Comment: But that's not the point here. This is more of a question in logic, then it is in set theory. The point is that "finite" is a notion internal to the universe of set theory, so it is a first-order property there. On the other hand, if you work in a different language (e.g. ordered sets) then the statement "Every bounded set is a least upper bound" is not a first-order statement, since it quantifies over subsets rather than the elements of the universe (which in this case is some linear/partial order).

Answer (score 1):

But all the elements of the universe are sets. Functions too. In set theory the power set is just an element, and its elements are also just ordinary objects too.

So when you say "quantify over all subsets and functions" we really just quantify over objects of the universe of sets. So it is a first order statement saying that certain objects do not exist in the universe.

From a[n internal] set theoretic perspective, second order logic means quantifying over proper classes.

Answer (score 0):

In Dirk van Dalen's book, logic and structure, 5th edition, P107, middle part
"finiteness is not a first-order property".