# Formulating that the universe is finite without establishing an upper limit

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, higher-order-logic

There is a fairly common example of a 2nd order formula that is only true in a universe with infinite domain:

$$\begin{align}
\exists R \quad & \forall x && \lnot xRx \\
          \land & \forall x \exists y && x R y \\
          \land & \forall x \forall y && x R y \implies \lnot y R x \\
          \land & \forall x \forall y \forall z && x R y \land y R z \implies x R z \\
\end{align}$$

And it is fairly easy to establish a formula that is only true in a finite universe:

$$\exists x \forall y~ x = y$$

which has only 1 element in the universe, or

$$\exists x_1 \exists x_2 \forall y ~x_1 = y \lor x_2 = y$$

which has no more than 2 elements in the universe.  Is there a formula that only holds when the universe is finite without putting an upper finite limit on its size?  In other words, it would be consistent with any formula of the form $\exists x_1 \dots \exists x_n \forall y ~ x_1 = y \lor \dots \lor x_n = y$ ?  I would be interested even if the formula was a higher order (quantified over relations or functions) formula; however, I am mostly interested in formulas with no free variables and no unquantified constants.

Comment: Can't you just negate your first formula?

Comment: @martini I guess you could if you assume "every possible relation exists".  The first relation isn't equivalent to "the universe is infinite", it just implies that.

Comment: Finiteness is not a first-order property. The following may help:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222319/how-can-we-express-finiteness-as-a-first-order-property
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894/why-is-the-finitely-many-quantifier-not-definable-in-first-order-logic

Comment: Just negate the existence of surjective non injective functional relations.

Comment: I have to pack up and go on a trip, I'll finish reading the responses when I get there, thanks Amir, nombre, martini.

Comment: @DanielV I think your sentence **is** equivalent to "the universe is infinite", at least assuming the axiom of choice . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical predicate $S$ forms a "finite system" if and only if:

$$\begin{array} {rl}
%
\forall F ~:~ & \left(\begin{array} {rrrl}
%
         & \forall a,~ b ~:~     &                 F(a,~ b) & \implies S(a) \land S(b)                      \\
\land    & \forall a ~:~         &                     S(a) & \implies \exists b ~:~ (S(b) \land F(a,~ b))  \\
\land    & \forall a,~ b,~ c ~:~ &  F(a,~ b) \land F(a,~ c) & \implies b=c                                  \\
\land    & \forall a,~ b,~ c ~:~ &  F(a,~ b) \land F(c,~ b) & \implies a=c                                  \\
\implies & \forall a ~:~         &                     S(a) & \implies \exists b ~:~ (S(b) \land F(b,~ a))  \\
%
\end{array}\right)\end{array}$$

You might think of this as the second-order predicate logic version of Dedekind finite, with $F$ being a kind of "mapping" from $S$ to $S$.

Comment: You can turn this into a **second-order** sentence asserting that the domain is finite - that is, $\exists S \exists F . . . $" - but you cannot do this in a first-order manner. Along these lines, note that there are infinite $\{S, F\}$-structures which do not satisfy your sentence - for instance, interpret $F$ and $S$ as the emptyset.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Non-empty F now assured by $\exists a,b: F(a,b)$. Non-empty S then assured by next line, $\forall a,b: [F(a,b) \implies S(a) \land S(b)]$

Comment: You're missing my point - I was giving an example of a structure which does **not** satisfy your sentence. My point is, there is no first order sentence $\varphi$ in any language $L$ which is true in exactly the infinite $L$-structures. (Actually, I was misreading your sentence in my previous comment - I thought you *did* include an axiom saying $F$ was nonempty.)

Comment: The proof of this is a straightforward application of compactness - consider the theory $T$ which is $\neg \varphi$ together with the sentences "there are at least $n$ elements" for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber See changes

Comment: So now this is a second-order sentence - note that this is essentially different from the negation of what the OP has written in the beginning of their post, although they express the same thing at the end of the day.

Comment: "If every total injective function from S to S is surjective, then S is finite".  Is that the correct intent of the expression?

Comment: I tentatively believe this answers my (possibly ambiguous) question, since $S(x)$ can just be replaced with $\top$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is negative. It is a well-known theorem (see for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_class)) that the class of all finite structures is not elementary, i.e. there is not first-order theory $T$ such that its models are all and only the finite structures.

This is a typical example of the limits of the expressive power of first-order logic with respect to second-order logic.

Comment: Theorem: If  a theory has arbitrarily large finite models ,it has an infinite model. So if a theory has no infinite model there must be an upper bound on the size off the model. This does not mean however that the value of the l.u.b. is decidable.

Comment: @user254665 Actually, for finite theories this **is** decidable: if there *is* a model of size $n$, we can find it, and if there is no model of size $\ge m$, then the theory proves the sentence "there is no model of size $\ge m$." So there is a Turing machine $\Phi$ such that, if $T$ is (a real coding) a finite theory with no infinite models, $\Phi^T(0)$ is the sup of the sizes of the models of $T$.

Comment: Note that the restriction to finite theories is necessary: we can find a computable function $f$ from numbers to theories such that (1) $f(n)$ never has a model of size $\ge 3$, and (2) $f(n)$ has a model of size $2$ iff $n$ is in the Halting Problem. The finiteness assumption is used in my claim that "if there *is* a model of size $n$, we can find it" - checking whether a *single* sentence holds in a finite model is recursive.

Comment: @Noah Schweber could you maybe give a reference for that? :) sounds interesting, and I'd need some more details to really understand how this works

Answer (score 1):

As remarked above, there is no first-order sentence which will do the job. On the other hand, we *can* get second-order examples; the negation of the sentence at the beginning of your post, or Dan Christensen's example, will both do the job.

. . . Unless the axiom of choice fails!

**WAIT, WHAT?**

So here's the deal: consider the second-order sentence "There is an injection from the universe to itself which is not a surjection." (This is basically the sentence from Dan's answer.) It is *not* the case that this sentence is true in every infinite universe, if the axiom of choice fails! It is consistent that there are **infinite Dedekind-finite sets** - infinite sets with no non-surjective self-injections. (It can get worse - there can be **amorphous sets**, which are infinite sets which cannot be partitioned into two infinite subsets!)

These "quasi-finite" sets might make you worry: is there a second-order sentence which characterizes exactly the finite sets, *without any choice*?

The answer, luckily, is yes: a set $X$ is *finite* iff there is a binary relation $R$ on $X$ such that:

- $R$ is a linear order - that is, transitivity, reflexivity, totality, and antisymmetry hold;
- $R$ has a first and last element, and every non-last element has a successor; and
- every surjective map from $X$ to itself is injective.

Clearly any finite set satisfies the above. Meanwhile, if a set $X$ existed which was not finite but satisfied the above, we could consider the subset $Y$ of $X$ consisting of all the elements of $X$ reachable by applying "successor" to the first element of $X$ finitely many times. If $X$ is infinite, then $Y$ has order type $\omega$, and so we can apply the usual "Hilbert's Hotel" argument.

It is a good exercise to express the definition of finiteness given above in second-order logic.

Comment: Note the shift here: the other definitions of finiteness are of the form "there is **no** function such that . . . " whereas this one is of the form "there **is some** function such that . . ."